# Am i using it correctly for protecting routes in Vuejs and Vuex?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuex

I am building a SPA in Vue.js and Laravel. I am using laravel passport for token based authentication. I am facing problems with protecting Vue routes. I am using Vue router navigation guard. I am storing the token and user when user log in. I am also fetching the user in app.js when user reload the page and storing token and user in vuex. The problem is the user is always null inside router.beforeEach when calling from vuex. my app.js looks like this

```
require('./bootstrap');

import store from './store/index'
import router from './router/index'
import VueToast from 'vue-toast-notification';
import 'vue-toast-notification/dist/theme-sugar.css';

window.Vue = require('vue').default;
Vue.use(VueToast);

store.dispatch('user/fetchUser');

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    router
});
```

I have solved it somehow but I am not sure if it is efficient or it will fail later. Now i am getting the user inside router.beforeEach. After solving app.js looks like this

```
require('./bootstrap');

import store from './store/index'
import router from './router/index'
import VueToast from 'vue-toast-notification';
import 'vue-toast-notification/dist/theme-sugar.css';

window.Vue = require('vue').default;
Vue.use(VueToast);

store.dispatch('user/fetchUser').then(() => {
    
    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        store,
        router
    });

});
```

I am fetching the user first then creating the vue instance when the promise resolves. Is it ok to do that or it will fail later?

There is another question in my mind. Should I get rid of fetching user and only check if there is a token in localStorage and protect routes by checking token.